# Regarding the alignment of shape inside the \table environment. How to center the table and rounded rectangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, vertical-alignment, center

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[left = 0.5in, right = 0.5in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\scalebox{4}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\rowcolor[gray]{0.68}\multicolumn{6}{c}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw = none, color = white, fill = gray!50, rounded rectangle, xshift = 0cm, yshift= 3cm] {\scriptsize ABCDEF BEDDDD TTTTTTT P}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{0.2cm}}\\
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.97}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.97} 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.97}13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.97}19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.97}25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Though it's somehow in the title, please give us a bit more background, best inside the question, not as a comment. // Do you want to create calendars? // Thank you

Comment: Actually I want to align rounded rectangle which is at the top and the table which seems misaligned to the center. Though I have added align to center by using \multicolumn{6}{c} but still I feel my shape isn't aligned verticallly as well as horizontally. I tried \tikzpicture inside \table enviroment. A

Answer (score 0):

You have a spurious space after the `tikzpicture` which throws off the centring. Simply remove that space:

```
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [color = white, font=\scriptsize, fill = gray!50, rounded rectangle, yshift= 3cm] {ABCDEF BEDDDD TTTTTTT P}; 
          \end{tikzpicture}%
```

However, use of `\scalebox` isn't recommended. It would be better to alter your font sizes, especially if you are using fonts which provide optical sizes.

For example,

```
    \centering
    \LARGE
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.68}\multicolumn{6}{c}{
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [color = white, font=\small, fill = gray!50, rounded rectangle,align=center, yshift= 3cm] {ABCDEF BEDDDD TTTTTTT P}; 
          \end{tikzpicture}%
          \vspace*{0.2cm}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.97}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 
        \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.97} 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 
        \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.97}13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.97}19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\ 
        \hline
        \rowcolor[gray]{0.97}25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30\\ 
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
```

You might also wish to look at `booktabs` for guidance on typesetting professional quality tabulars, but perhaps this is more matrix than tabular?